# Cannot access changes and create projects

Tags: gerrit

Tried gerrit 2.15 and 2.16.6.

I'm trying to migrate an existing gerrit instance to another hardware.
There is an AOSP mirror with old changes and database.

I've moved everything to the new hardware and can see a list of changes and a list of projects, but I can't access any changes themselves. When I click to access some change, I receive 404 not found and a message ***"Server error: Not found: root-dir"***. 
When I try to create a new project with the name ***"root-dir/project_path/project_name"***, I receive the same message.

Cgroups configurations are correct.
Reindexing doesn't help, neither does reinitializing.

Using `ssh` I can create a project and pull any change I want.

The only difference between configurations is that now we use nginx in front of a gerrit instance.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in an nginx configuration.

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[ipv6_address]:8443/;
        ...
    }
}
```

The slash at the end caused the issue: should be `proxy_pass http://[ipv6_address]:8443;`

[Issue 1999: creating project with a / will cause an error (404 not found)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1999)

[Troubleshooting](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html#_troubleshooting_2)